# Why is my array erased when passed as argument?

Tags: c, arrays, function, memory-address

I'm having issues with a function I created. Here is a code-sample :

```
#include <stdio.h>    // EDIT
static void my_function(int size, float my_array[size+1]);
int main(void)
{
    int size = 3, i;
    float my_array[size+1];
    for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
        my_array[i]=0.5;
    my_function(size, my_array);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
static void my_function(int size, float my_array[size+1])
{
    printf("my_array[0] = %f\n", my_array[0]);    // Segmentation fault here !
}
```

After some debugging and some research I discovered that `my_array` had the value `0x0` in `my_function`. I guess this is the reason of the segmentation fault.

Am I right ? If so, how can I solve this ? If not, what is the problem then ?

Comment: You must have a globally defined `size` variable for `float my_array[size+1]` to compile, so maybe it conflicts with your `size = 3` variable in main.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/27CyWf) -- you forgot to `#include <stdio.h>`.

Comment: Also forgot `<stdlib.h>` (for EXIT_SUCCESS).

Comment: @irrelephant the `size` in `my_array[size+1]` refers to the initial parameter. Although this would be a variable-sized array, this doesn't matter since array parameters decay to pointers anyway. The code compiles, at least with gcc.

Comment: @davmac Ah, I see. Never mind, then.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the `#include stdio.h` was written in my code. I simply forgot to copy it in my question...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the stdio.h header in your file, here is another interesting way of doing the same thing that you originally wanted to do

```
#include <stdio.h>
static void my_function(int size, float *my_array);
int main(void)
{
    int size = 3, i;
    float my_array[size+1];
    for(i=0;i<=size;i++)
        my_array[i]=0.5;
    my_function(size, my_array);
    return 0;
}
static void my_function(int size, float *my_array)
{
    printf("my_array[0] = %f\n", my_array[0]);    // No Segmentation fault now, using array indexes!
    printf("*(my_array) =%f\n", *(my_array));     //Using de-reference method
}
```

EDIT: I ran using the original code using gcc and as @davmac suggested, the issue was indeed the fact that the stdio.h header file had not been included. But the method used above is quiet intutive and good for understanding as well

Comment: Nope. An array parameter works. I suspect the real problem was lack of inclusion of <stdio.h>.

Comment: What you did is what already happen, array parameters are just pointer parameters, and when calling the function the array argument is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: You guys are right, I overlooked it in a hurry, I have made the edit. Cheers

Comment: lesson for OP; may attention to compiler warnings! The original code must have warned about missing stdio.

Comment: Thanks everyone, the `#include stdio.h` was written in my code. I simply forgot to copy it in my question..

Answer (score 1):

You program is not standard C. Ok it compiles and runs fine with `gcc` (once you add the relevant includes `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`) but it could not even compile on a stricter compiler.

In following declaration :

```
float my_array[size+1];
```

the size of the array is a variable. C requires it is a constant expression. From Gnu C reference manual : *Another GNU extension allows you to declare an array size using variables, rather than only constants*

Your function declaration :

```
static void my_function(int size, float my_array[size+1])
```

is not standard C either. In standard C, you should write :

```
static void my_function(int size, float my_array[])
```

or

```
static void my_function(int size, float *my_array)
```

Gnu C accepts it (and even sizeof on the array), but it may be misleading. I modified your function that way :

```
static void my_function(int size, float my_array[size+1])
{
    int i = sizeof(my_array);
    printf("size : %d/%d : %d\n", i, sizeof(float), i/sizeof(float));
    printf("my_array[0] = %f\n", my_array[0]);    // Segmentation fault here !
}
```

and the result is :

```
size : 8/4 : 2
my_array[0] = 0.500000
```

I really do not know where gcc found the size, but it is **not** what you could expect.

All that means that from a C language point of view, compilers could raise errors, and even if they don't, you may have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
after fixing all the compiler warnings 
all warnings really need to be enabled during the compile step
and all warnings really do need to be fixed
then using a float value, rather than a double value to init the array
then the following code compiles cleanly

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void my_function(float *my_array);

#define SIZE (4)

int main()
{
    float my_array[SIZE] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f };

    my_function(my_array);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
} // end function: main

static void my_function(float *my_array)
{
    printf("my_array[0] = %f\n", my_array[0]);
} // end function: my_function
```

Answer (score -3):

Write like this: 
void my_function(int size, float *my_arr);
When you're passing array's name as a parameter to a function, the function use it like a pointer.So you can write a pointer as a parameter. PS:Array's name is not a pointer.

Comment: This isn't an answer, see comments to Khan's one.